# Narrow return type of dynamically constructed object in function

Tags: typescript

I have the following construction function

```
function make(x: string) {
     const result: { [k: string]: any } = {};
     result[x] = true
     result.kind = x
     return result
}
```

that upon usage like the below

```
let a = make("A")
```

will create an object of "type"

```
{
    A: true,
    kind: "A"
}
```

and when used with a "B"

```
let b = make("B")
```

will create an object of "type"

```
{
    B: true,
    kind: "B"
}
```

now both `a` and `b` will be of type `any` in absence of type signature. However I'd like to have a more concrete return type than any. Something similar to

```
function make(x: string): { $x-val: bool; kind: $x-val } { ....
```

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 2):

The following type description does the trick

```
type TT<X extends string> = 
    (Record<X, true> & Record<"kind", X>) extends infer O ? 
    { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : 
    never

function make<T extends string>(x: T): TT<T> {
    const result: { [k: string]: any } = {};
    result[x] = true
    result.kind = x
    return result as TT<T>
}
```